# Written a cucumber code and tried to execute in Maven, browser is invoke but it is not giving the URL in the browser

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber

The pom.xml is as below

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>mavenproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>mavenproject</name>

  <properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <webdriver.driver>iexplorer</webdriver.driver>
  <webdriver.iexplorer>D:/IEDriverServer_x64_3.12.0/IEDriverServer.exe</webdriver.iexplorer>
  <webdriver.iexplorer.driver>${webdriver.iexplorer}</webdriver.iexplorer.driver>
  <site.url>https://www.openbetcareers.com/</site.url>
    <browser.name>iexplorer</browser.name>
  </properties>

  <description>manvenproject</description>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.45.0</version>
  </dependency>


    <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency> 

  </dependencies>
  <profiles>
  <profile>
  <id>cucumber-tests</id>
  <build>
  <plugins>

  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
  <includes>
  <include>**/RunTest.java</include>
  </includes>
  <goals>
  <goal>integration-test</goal>
  <goal>verify</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
  <glue>mavenproject.stepdefinition</glue>
  <featuresDirectory>src/test/java/featurefile/</featuresDirectory>
  </configuration>
  <systemProperties>
  <webdriver.driver>${webdriver.driver}</webdriver.driver>
  <surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount>${surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount</surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount>
  </systemProperties>
  <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
  <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
  </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3</version>
  <configuration>
  <source>1.8</source>
  <target>1.8</target>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
  </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

**RunTest.java** is as below:

```
package mavenproject.stepdefinition;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features="src/test/java/mavenproject/featurefile",glue={"mavenproject.stepdefinition"}


        )

public class RunTest {


}
```

Comment: Please tell us your problem is and what you've already tried to solve the issue. Also have a look at [this help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you might be referring the driver properties declared in maven pom.xml incorrectly in your step definition class file which has the driver implementation.